# Rails live_validations inside ajax loaded modal

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm running an old Rails 2.3 app and I'm having trouble in having live_validations work on a form inside an AJAX-loaded modal.

Here is the page I AJAX-load inside the modal:

```
<div class="central_content">   
    <%= t("flags_.form_title") %>
    <% form_for (@flag, :remote => true, :live_validations => true) do |f| %>

        <%= hidden_field_tag (:post_id, @flag.post_id) %>

        <%= f.text_area :explanation, :placeholder => t("flags_.explanation") %>
        <%= f.submit t("messages_.send"), :class => "nice_small_butt red" %>

    <% end %>
</div>
```

When the modal opens I get:

```
TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function
```

This is the code that Rails writes

```
<div class="central_content">   
    <h1>Motiva la tua segnalazione </h1>

    <form action="/flags" class="new_flag" id="new_flag" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="y5qw6kodM4/rzcYDf1xtx364uzN3izjm+ZsTpfbUmHA=" /></div>

        <input id="post_id" name="post_id" type="hidden" value="31252" />

        <textarea cols="40" id="flag_explanation" name="flag[explanation]" placeholder="Indica qui i motivi della tua segnalazione (es: &quot;La documentazione è insufficiente, tanto che...&quot;, &quot;Il testo dell'istruzione non è stato rispettato infatti...&quot;, ecc..).  La tua motivazione comparirà all'interno di una mail più ampia che i Comunity Ninja di Upload riceveranno, quindi cerca di essere il più specifico e dettagliato possibile nello spiegare cosa rende l'esecuzione non valida e cosa secondo te dovrebbe essere fatto per rimediare." rows="20"></textarea>
        <input class="nice_small_butt red" id="flag_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Invia" />

    </form><script type="text/javascript">

          $('#new_flag').validate({"messages":{},"ignore":".ignore","rules":{"flag[explanation]":{"minlength":80}}})
        </script>
</div>
```

It seems that the Jquery code generated by Rails for live_validation is not working after the AJAX call.  How can I fix this?

I'm using Jquery 1.7.1 which is loaded before jQuery Validation Plugin - v1.11.1

Comment: Are you sure it's the Rails live validations & not JQuery validations?

Comment: Rich, what do you mean?  How can I check this?

Comment: Well you mention that you're looking to check the validations on the front-end using the `.validate` function in javascript. I don't know Rails 2, but you mentioned that `live_validation` is not working -- I presumed this was a Rails function? If it was JQuery, it would be caused by the element not appearing in the DOM, but if it's a RAILS function, it could be different

Comment: Rick, it seems that I'm using the validate jquery plugin but it isn't loaded by the page, although it appears in the loaded scripts in Firebug.  Don't know why...

Comment: How are you loading it in the page? Are you trying to bind to an element which loads dynamically?

Comment: I was loading using javascript_include_tag and it wasn't loading.  Just tried to load it with explicit script tag in header and now it loads!

Comment: Also the validation now works, except it allows a blank field submission even if the Rails model has:

validates_length_of :explanation, :minimum => 80, :allow_nil => false, :allow_blank => false

Comment: Added also this to model:

validates_presence_of :explanation

Comment: Now everything works.  Thank you Rick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that the plugin was not properly loaded.
I was trying to load the Jquery validation plugin using javascript_include_tag.

Switched to an explicit  and now everything works.